Normality of the lower central series
The lower central series of a group $G$ is defined as follows:
$$
\gamma_1(G) = G, \quad \gamma_{i+1}(G) = [\gamma_i(G), G],
$$
where $[\gamma_i(G), G]$ denotes the subgroup generated by all commutators $[x, y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, with $x \in \gamma_i(G)$ and $y \in G$.
I am trying to prove that each subgroup $\gamma_i(G)$ is normal in $G$, without using the fact that $\gamma_i(G)$ is characteristic and then they normal . I already know this standard proof, but I am curious if there is an alternative proof that avoids these ideas.
Here is what I have tried so far:

List item
By definition, $[x, y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in \gamma_{i}(G)$, which is equivalent to saying $xyx^{-1} \in \gamma_i(G)$.
I attempted to show that $\gamma_{i+1}(G) \subseteq \gamma_i(G)$ implies that $\gamma_i(G)$ is normal in $G$. However, I got stuck at this point.

Could you let me know if there is a proof of the normality of $\gamma_i(G)$ that does not require showing it is characteristic then normal?
Thank you for any assistance!

To be more precise, I do not want to use that since these subgroups are characteristic, and therefore preserved by inner automorphisms. For example, we can prove that the derived group is normal without explicitly stating that it is characteristic.

I think that repeated use of $[x_{1} x_{2}, y]=[x_{1}^{x_2},y^{x_2}][x_2,y]$ and induction gives a proof that does not overtly say that the $\gamma_i$ are characteristic. But the whole project seems to me perverse.

We will try to prove that $\gamma_n(G) \lhd G$ by induction. This is clearly true for $n=1$ as $\gamma_1(G)=G \lhd G$.
Now suppose we know that $\gamma_n(G) \lhd G$.
Now consider $\gamma_{n+1}(G)$. It is generated by commutators $[x,y]$ where $x \in \gamma_n(G)$ and $y \in G$.
If we can show that for any $z \in G$, $z[x,y]z^{-1} \in \gamma_{n+1}(G)$, that will suffice to prove that for any $x \in \gamma_{n+1}(G)$, $zxz^{-1} \in \gamma_{n+1}(G)$.
So consider $zxyx^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}$. Rewrite it as $(zxz^{-1})(zyz^{-1})(zx^{-1}z^{-1})(zy^{-1}z^{-1}) = [zxz^{-1},zyz^{-1}]$.
$zxz^{-1} \in \gamma_n(G)$ because $\gamma_n(G) \lhd G$ (induction hypothesis), and $zyz^{-1} \in G$ of course. So by definition of $\gamma_{n+1}(G)$, we have $[zxz^{-1},zyz^{-1}] = z[x,y]z^{-1} \in \gamma_{n+1}(G)$.
So we are done!

Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for.
